# Getting the minimum value from the list

Tags: python, list, class, object, oop

I am trying to retrieve the author,name,viewers,cost details who viewers is less in the given magazine collection as input i.e list

I am beginner of python

The code I tried is:

```
class Magazine:
    def __init__(self,Author,Viewers,Cost,Name):
        self.Author=Author
        self.Viewers=Viewers
        self.Cost=Cost
        self.Name = Name
        
class Publisher:
    def __init__(self,magazineCollection):
        self.magazineCollection = magazineCollection
    def findMinimumMagazineByViewers(self,Magazine):
        empty=[]
        for i in self.Magazine:
            if min(i.viewers):
                empty.append(i.Name,i.Author,i.Viewers,i.Cost)
                print(empty)
if __name__=='__main__':
    l=[['satya',24,320,'S'],['lakshmi',23,340,'L']]
    obj=Publisher(l)
    obj1=obj.findMinimumMagazineByViewers(l)
    print(obj1)
```

The error is:
AttributeError: 'Publisher' object has no attribute 'Magazine'

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: `Magazine` is param input to method `findMinimumMagazineByViewers`. You never made it class attribute like `self.Magazine = Magazine`

Comment: You iterate over `self.Magazine`. It doesn't exist. Did you mean to iterate over `self.magazineCollection` (the attribute) or over the `Magazine` passed to the method as an argument? It looks like they're the same thing, which makes no sense.

Comment: `l` is a list of lists. It should be a list of `Magazine`, no?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes list of magazines from that I want to get one magazine details which consists of lesser viewers

Comment: Also, shouldn't the parameter to `findMinimumMagazineByViewers` be a number?

Comment: yes @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Please use the naming conventions from the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). As the code is now, it's hard to read for an experienced dveloper.

Answer (score 0):

You could to create a list of `Magazines` to make it searchable:

```
class Magazine:
    def __init__(self, Author, Viewers, Cost, Name):
        self.Author = Author
        self.Viewers = Viewers
        self.Cost = Cost
        self.Name = Name


class Publisher:
    def __init__(self, magazineCollection):
        # create all magazines
        self.magazineCollection = [Magazine(*m) for m in magazineCollection]

    def findMinimumMagazineByViewers(self):
        empty = []

        # filter my minimum Viewers and return the Magazine instance
        i = min(self.magazineCollection, key=lambda x: x.Viewers)
        empty.append((i.Name, i.Author, i.Viewers, i.Cost))
        return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [['satya', 24, 320, 'S'], ['lakshmi', 23, 340, 'L']]
    obj = Publisher(l)
    obj1 = obj.findMinimumMagazineByViewers()
    print(obj1.__dict__)
```

Out:

```
{'Author': 'lakshmi', 'Viewers': 23, 'Cost': 340, 'Name': 'L'}
```